# php plain text email formats differently in outlook

Tags: php, formatting, outlook, email, thunderbird

I'm trying to align some text in a php generated plain text email. 
Thunderbird displays all characters as the same width. Newer versions of Outlook however do not. Is there some way I can force outlook to use a "fixed-width" font in the headers for instance?

Here are the headers I'm currently using

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Answer (score 1):

This is because Outlook 2010 by default displays plain text as a proportional rather than fixed width font.

> If you want Outlook 2010 to display these messages like 2003 did, then
> you can specify Courier New as the Plain Text font, using these steps:
>
> 1. On the File tab, click Options.
> 2. Click Mail.
> 3. Click "Stationery and Fonts"
> 4. Click the Font button under "Composing and reading plain text messages"
> 5. On the Font tab, change the font settings.
> 6. Click OK three times.

From http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/outlook/thread/6a354c78-64d8-4b68-9651-0f1d33c950ac

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending HTML email? If so, Outlook won't use fixed-width fonts.

Try specifying your content type to:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

... using something like:

```
$headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: I am using those headers... Sorry I should've mentioned that. I still couldn't get it to work

Comment: Can you post the (censored) headers of the resulting email?

Comment: To: someone@somewhere.com
Subject: Email subject
From: someone@somewhere.com
Reply-To: someone@somewhere.com
CC: 
Message-Id: <20100224001004.8CAE9278002@somwhere.com>
Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2010 11:10:04 +1100 (EST)

Comment: No mention of Content-Type or charset

Answer (score 0):

It's a user preference. Both Outlook and Thunderbird may be configured to use monospaced or proportional fonts. I use Thunderbird with proportional fonts.

You can't force an override short of sending HTML mail with a `<pre>` tag or suitable CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Or, better yet, send the e-mail in the HTML format and specify the appropriate fixed width font.